# Self set welcomer help discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would i make this code be able to be set by other server owners in their desired channels with a command i've tried multiple attempts but they never seem to work!

````
#WELCOME COMMAND
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    print(Fore.CYAN + current_time,
          f"{member} has joined {member.guild}" + Fore.RESET)
    case = client.get_channel(769654443708252161)
    if case:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f"Welcome to {member.guild} {member.name}", color=0x0000, timestamp=datetime.now(),)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(icon_url=member.avatar_url, text=f"ID: {member.id} • {current_time}",)
        await case.send(f" ||{member.mention}||", embed=embed)
    else:
        return


#GOODBYE COMMAND
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    goodbye = client.get_channel(769656514297200710)
    await goodbye.send(f"Thank you come again {member.mention} .")```
````

Comment: These are events. Have you tried creating a ```bot.command()```?

Comment: yes i have the events are because that's the on join/leave messages i just need a command to be able to set them to whatever channels they want

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this save channel ids in a dictionary or a json file.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

channel_ids = {}

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

    channel = channel_ids[member.guild.id]
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Welcome to {member.guild} {member.name}", color=0x0000, timestamp=datetime.now(),)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url=member.avatar_url, text=f"ID: {member.id} • {current_time}",)
    await bot.get_channel(channel).send(f" ||{member.mention}||", embed=embed)
```